# Android CustomRecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my Custom recyclerview class, this recyclreview class keeps the selected position at center, i want to show selected item proetically at on-create
Here im getting NullpointerException
recyclerlist Contains 9 items,

Thanks in advance...!

from activity

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rv.enableViewScaling(true);

 categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(this,list,rv.getMeasuredWidth());

    rv.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

    rv.setOnViewSelectedListener(new SnappingRecyclerView.OnViewSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelected(View view, int position) {

            Toast.makeText(ExpencessActivity.this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    rv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            rv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            rv.setSelectedItem(8);
        }
    });
```

**//Here im getting NullpointerException
recyclerlist Contains 9 items,**

```
public class SnappingRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

private boolean _userScrolling = false;

private boolean mScaleUnfocusedViews = false;
private boolean _scrolling = false;
private int _scrollState = SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
private long _lastScrollTime = 0;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private boolean _scaleViews = false;
private Orientation _orientation = Orientation.HORIZONTAL;

private boolean mSnapEnabled = false;

private ChildViewMetrics _childViewMetrics;
public OnViewSelectedListener _listener;
private int _selectedPosition;
private int selectedItem = 0;

private final static int MINIMUM_SCROLL_EVENT_OFFSET_MS = 20;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

public SnappingRecyclerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SnappingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SnappingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setHasFixedSize(true);
    setOrientation(_orientation);
    enableSnapping();
}

private boolean scrolling;

@Override
public void onChildAttachedToWindow(View child) {
    super.onChildAttachedToWindow(child);
    if (!scrolling && _scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ) {
        scrolling = true;
        isChildCorrectlyCentered(child);
        scrollToView(getCenterView());
        updateViews();
    }
}

public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    setSelectedPosition(selectedItem);
}

private void enableSnapping() {
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });

    addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            updateViews();
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            /* if scroll is caused by a touch (scroll touch, not any touch) **/
            if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                /* if scroll was initiated already, it would probably be a tap **/
                /* if scroll was not initiated before, this is probably a user scrolling **/
                if (!_scrolling) {
                    _userScrolling = true;
                }
            } else if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                /* if user is the one scrolling, snap to the view closest to center **/
                if (_userScrolling) {
                    scrollToView(getCenterView());
                }

                _userScrolling = false;
                _scrolling = false;

                /* if idle, always check location and correct it if necessary, this is just an extra check **/
                if (getCenterView() != null && getPercentageFromCenter(getCenterView()) > 0) {
                    scrollToView(getCenterView());
                }

                /* if idle, notify listeners of new selected view **/
                notifyListener();
            } else if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                _scrolling = true;
            }

            _scrollState = newState;
        }
    });
}

private void notifyListener() {
    View view = getCenterView();
    int position = getChildAdapterPosition(view);

    /* if there is a listener and the index is not the same as the currently selected position, notify listener **/
    if (_listener != null && position != _selectedPosition) {
        _listener.onSelected(view, position);
    }

    _selectedPosition = position;
}

/**
 * Set the orientation for this SnappingRecyclerView
 * @param orientation LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL or LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
 */
public void setOrientation(Orientation orientation) {
    this._orientation = orientation;
    _childViewMetrics = new ChildViewMetrics(_orientation);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), _orientation.intValue(), false) ;
    setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

/**
 * Set the OnViewSelectedListener
 * @param listener the OnViewSelectedListener
 */
public void setOnViewSelectedListener(OnViewSelectedListener listener) {
    this._listener = listener;
}

/**
 * Enable downscaling of views which are not focused, based on how far away they are from the center
 * @param enabled enable or disable the scaling behaviour
 */
public void enableViewScaling(boolean enabled) {
    this._scaleViews = enabled;
}

private void updateViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        setMarginsForChild(child);

        if (_scaleViews) {
            float percentage = getPercentageFromCenter(child);
            float scale = 1f - (1f * percentage);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    }
}

/**
 *  Adds the margins to a childView so a view will still center even if it's only a single child
 * @param child childView to set margins for
 */
private void setMarginsForChild(View child) {
    int lastItemIndex = getLayoutManager().getItemCount() - 1;
    int childIndex = getChildAdapterPosition(child);

    int startMargin = 0;
    int endMargin = 0;
    int topMargin = 0;
    int bottomMargin = 0;

    if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        topMargin = childIndex == 0 ? getCenterLocation() : 0;
        bottomMargin = childIndex == lastItemIndex ? getCenterLocation() : 0;
    } else {
        startMargin = childIndex == 0 ? getCenterLocation() : 0;
        endMargin = childIndex == lastItemIndex ? getCenterLocation() : 0;
    }

    /* if sdk minimum level is 17, set RTL margins **/
    if (_orientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        ((MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).setMarginStart(startMargin);
        ((MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).setMarginEnd(endMargin);
    }

    /* If layout direction is RTL, swap the margins  **/
    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(child) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        ((MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(endMargin, topMargin, startMargin, bottomMargin);
    } else {
        ((MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(startMargin, topMargin, endMargin, bottomMargin);
    }

    /* if sdk minimum level is 18, check if view isn't undergoing a layout pass (this improves the feel of the view by a lot) **/
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        if (!child.isInLayout())
            child.requestLayout();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /* if touch events are being spammed, this is due to user scrolling right after a tap,
      so set userScrolling to true **/
    if (_scrolling && _scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
        if ((currentTime - _lastScrollTime) < MINIMUM_SCROLL_EVENT_OFFSET_MS) {
            _userScrolling = true;
        }
    }

    _lastScrollTime = currentTime;

    int location = _orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL ? (int)event.getY() : (int)event.getX();

    View targetView = getChildClosestToLocation(location);

    if (!_userScrolling) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (targetView != getCenterView()) {
                scrollToView(targetView);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int location = _orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL ? (int) event.getY() : (int) event.getX();

    View targetView = getChildClosestToLocation(location);

    return targetView != getCenterView() || super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
    _childViewMetrics.size(getChildAt(0));
    smoothScrollBy(_childViewMetrics.size(getChildAt(0)) * position);
}

private View getChildClosestToLocation(int location) {
    if (getChildCount() <= 0)
        return null;

    int closestPos = 9999;
    View closestChild = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        int childCenterLocation = (int) _childViewMetrics.center(child);
        int distance = childCenterLocation - location;

        /* if child center is closer than previous closest, set it as closest child  **/
        if (Math.abs(distance) < Math.abs(closestPos)) {
            closestPos = distance;
            closestChild = child;
        }
    }

    return closestChild;
}

/**
 * Check if the view is correctly centered (allow for 10px offset)
 * @param child the child view
 * @return true if correctly centered
 */
private boolean isChildCorrectlyCentered(View child) {
    int childPosition = (int)_childViewMetrics.center(child);
    return childPosition > (getCenterLocation() - 10) && childPosition < (getCenterLocation() + 10);
}

private View getCenterView() {
    return getChildClosestToLocation(getCenterLocation());
}

private void scrollToView(View child) {

    if (child == null)
        return;

    stopScroll();
    int scrollDistance = getScrollDistance(child);

    if (scrollDistance != 0)
        smoothScrollBy(scrollDistance);
}

private int getScrollDistance(View child) {
    int childCenterLocation = (int) _childViewMetrics.center(child);
    return childCenterLocation - getCenterLocation();
}

private float getPercentageFromCenter(View child) {
    float center = getCenterLocation();
    float childCenter = _childViewMetrics.center(child);

    float offSet = Math.max(center, childCenter) - Math.min(center, childCenter);
    float maxOffset = (center + _childViewMetrics.size(child));

    return (offSet / maxOffset);
}

private int getCenterLocation() {
    if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL)
        return getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

    return getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
}

public void smoothScrollBy(int distance) {
    if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        super.smoothScrollBy(0, distance);
        return;
    }

    super.smoothScrollBy(distance, 0);
}

public void scrollBy(int distance) {
    if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
        super.scrollBy(0, distance);
        return;
    }

    super.scrollBy(distance, 0);
}

private void scrollTo(int position) {
    int currentScroll = getScrollOffset();
    scrollBy(position - currentScroll);
}

public int getScrollOffset() {
    if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL)
        return computeVerticalScrollOffset();

    return computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
}

/**
 * Returns the currently centered item aka the selected item
 */
public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return _selectedPosition;
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}

private static class ChildViewMetrics {
    private Orientation _orientation;

    public ChildViewMetrics(Orientation orientation) {
        this._orientation = orientation;
    }

    public int size(View view) {
        if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL)
            return view.getHeight();
        return view.getWidth();
    }

    public float location(View view) {
        if (_orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL)
            return view.getY();
        return view.getX();
    }
    public float center(View view) {
        return location(view) + (size(view) / 2);
    }
}

public enum Orientation {
    HORIZONTAL(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL),
    VERTICAL(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int value;

    Orientation(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int intValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
    this._selectedPosition = selectedPosition;

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(_selectedPosition);

            if (viewHolder!=null) {
                View view = viewHolder.itemView;
                scrollToView(view);
            } else {
                scrollTo(260,0);
                setSelectedPosition(_selectedPosition);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public interface OnViewSelectedListener {
    void onSelected(View view, int position);
}
}
```

**// this is my Adapter Class**

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Category> categoryList;
private Context mContext;
int Width = 0;

public CategoriesAdapter(Context context,List<Category> categoryList,int Width) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
    this.Width = Width;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);

        itemView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (getScreenWidth() / 5);

        return new CategoryViewHolder(itemView);

}
private int getScreenWidth() {

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int itemViewType = getItemViewType(position);

        holder.updateView(categoryList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder   {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_img);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    }

    public void updateView(Category category)
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(category.getCategory_img_resorce());
        textView.setText(category.getCategory_name());
    }
}
```

// this is Error log
 {
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.thinuser.myapplication.HelperClass.SnappingRecyclerView$ChildViewMetrics.size(SnappingRecyclerView.java:394)

Comment: which line throws the NPE?

Comment: share the error log.

Comment: From Activity I was trying To call setSelectedItem metoed at oncreate of Activity it Was ViewHolder viewHolder = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(_selectedPosition); Viewholder nullpointer Exception